# Will it lead to a dead lock if app instance crashes when performing a transaction?

Tags: sql, transactions, deadlock

Suppose that we have three SQLs in one transaction. App instance performs begin transaction,and perform the first sql,then the app instance crashes. Will it lead to a dead lock or the resources locked by first SQL will never be released?

If it will not leads to dead lock,how the dbms achieve that goal? Is timeout mechanism used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app crashes, this means that the connection to the database is lost.

The database server will eventually notice this and will terminate the database session.

All database systems I know, will terminate the database session with a rollback, so anything that the app did, will be rolled back and all locks will be released. So there is no danger of getting into a deadlock situation.

How exactly this is done and how long it takes for the server to notice that the client (=app) is gone, depends on the actual DBMS product though.